# React App crashes when fetching searchresults from django API

Tags: reactjs, search, django-rest-framework

My React App is crashing when fetching searchResults from API, I have checked the API urls wise search queries and it works perfectly however when i try to send input via React and display results it crashes and even freezes my PC. I dont understand whats going on here. I have fetched results from the API in React without search query and it works.   So the API works when used via Curl and React app can fetch and display all the data but unable to display specific data. Below is my code:

```
function Search() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      getData(searchTerm);
    }
  });
  const getData = (searchTerm) => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/SearchPost/?search="+searchTerm)
         .then(res => (setData(res.data)))
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => (
          <li>{item.co_N}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Search;
```

Comment: may be is because you made to many request, every time a user enter a letter in the input it send a request to api.

Comment: here a [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ride-2094d?file=/src/searchPage.js) just change axios url with your api endpoint  and the display list ,
If that works and fix the issue I will post an answer for other user. Hope it helps

Comment: I'm using a development server right now on my own PC, I'm the only user and i havent added authentication to API yet. Also from i what i can see it is only making a single request for every letter input, but it crashes on a single input. At max it has to display 100 JSON objects.  @antoineso

Comment: Thanks. your code snippet works fine without blowing out the cpu. @antoineso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to "debounce" setting searchTerm to minimize the request to the API:
we're going to use lodash package particularly it's `debounce` method (doc [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce)), and `useCallback` from Hooks API (doc [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)) :

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import axios from "axios";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const SearchInputComponent = ({ label }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const debounceLoadData = useCallback(
    _.debounce((value) => {
      getData(value);
    }, 500), // you can set a higher value if you want
    []
  );

  const getData = (name) => {
    axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res.data);
    });
  };
  const handleSearchFieldChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    setValue(value);
    debounceLoadData(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        inputRef={inputRef}
        id="searchField"
        value={value}
        label={"search"}
        onChange={handleSearchFieldChange}
      />
      {data &&
<ul>
{data.map(country=>  (
<li key={country.alpha3Code}>{country.name}</li>
))

}

</ul>
}
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchInputComponent;
```

with this code the front end will wait 500 ms before fetching api with the search input value.

here a [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ride-2094d?file=/src/searchPage.js) example.

**Possible Feature: Make search field generic**

If in the future you will need a search component you can make it generic with [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper):
first create a context file named for example *SearchInputContext.js* and add: 
**SearchInputContext.js**

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useState
} from 'react';

export const SearchInputContext = createContext({});

export const SearchInputContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <SearchInputContext.Provider
      value={{ searchValue: value, setSearchValue: setValue }}
    >
      {children}
    </SearchInputContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Next create a generic searchField component named for example *SearchInput.js* and add in it : 
**SearchInput.js**

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  useContext
} from 'react';
import  _ from 'lodash';
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { SearchInputContext } from './SearchInputContext';

const SearchInputComponent  = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const { setSearchValue } = useContext(SearchInputContext);
 
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const debounceLoadData = useCallback(
    _.debounce((value) => {
      setSearchValue(value);
    }, 500),
    []
  );

  const handleSearchFieldChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    setValue(value);
    debounceLoadData(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
     <TextField
        inputRef={inputRef}
        id="searchField"
        value={value}
        label={"search"}
        onChange={handleSearchFieldChange}
      />
     
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchInputComponent;
```

After in your *App.js* (or other component page where you want a searchField) add  your ContextProvider like this:
**App.js**

```
import {ListPage} from "./searchPage";
import  {SearchInputContextProvider}  from './SearchInputContext';
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
   
<SearchInputContextProvider>
   <ListPage/>
    </SearchInputContextProvider>
   
  );
}
```

And finally add your searchComponent where you need a search feature like in the *ListPage* component : 
**SearchPage.js**:

```
import React, { useState,useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import SearchInputComponent from './SearchInput';
import {SearchInputContext} from './SearchInputContext'


export const ListPage = () => {
 
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const { searchValue } = useContext(SearchInputContext);
 
useEffect(() => {
if(searchValue){
  const getData = (name) => {
    axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${name}`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res.data);
    });
  };
 return getData(searchValue)

}
  
}, [ searchValue]);
 
  return (
    <>
     <SearchInputComponent  />
      {data &&
<ul>
{data.map(country=>  (
<li key={country.alpha3Code}>{country.name}</li>
))

}

</ul>
}
    </>
  );
};
```

here a sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-water-84qqu?file=/src/searchPage.js:0-769) of this example